# How do I fix this code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class AttendanceManager {

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    System.out.println("Enter the number of students that are to be recorded.");
    Scanner studentNum = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = studentNum.nextInt();
    final int number[] = new int[x]; 

    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter 1 if the student is present and 0 if the student is not.");
        final Scanner attendance = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inp = attendance.nextInt();
        int y = inp;
        switch (inp)
        {
        case 1:
            number[y] = 1;
            y = y++;
            break;
        case 0:
            number[y] = 2;
            y = y++;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 0.");
            i--; 
        }


    }
    System.out.println("Total Students: " + number.length);
    for(int k=0; k<number.length; k++)
    {
        if (number[k] == 1)
        System.out.println("Student " + (k+1) + " is " + "present.");
        else if (number[k] == 2)
        System.out.println("Student " + (k+1) + " is " + "absent.");
        else
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

}

Output:

```
Enter the number of students that are to be recorded.
5
Enter 1 if the student is present and 0 if the student is not.
1
Enter 1 if the student is present and 0 if the student is not.
0
Enter 1 if the student is present and 0 if the student is not.
1
Enter 1 if the student is present and 0 if the student is not.
1
Enter 1 if the student is present and 0 if the student is not.
0
Total Students: 5
Student 1 is absent.
Student 2 is present.
error
error
error
```

why do the last 3 not get assigned to 1 or 0?

Comment: `y=y++` is totally redundant. `y++` is the equivalent of `y=y+1`

Comment: `y=y++` doesn't even increment `y`

Comment: The modification of `y` is pointless anyway. You assign `inp` to `y` in every iteration. You surely want to use **`i`** as array index instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the WRONG array index:

```
    int inp = attendance.nextInt();
    int y = inp;
    switch (inp)
    {
    case 1:
        number[y] = 1;
        y = y++;
```

`y` is the value the user input, e.g. `1` or `0`, which you then use as your `number` array index. But since the user only enters `1` or `0`, you **NEVER** set array indexes `2`, `3`, `4`, etc... So you're trying to output array entries that never got defined.

It should be

```
  number[i] = 1;
         ^--
```

Answer (score 0):

You are introducing another counter `y` which has no use, just keep the `i` one alone.

As the possible values of `y` where 0 or 1 , none of the other indexes of your array would be populated correctly.

Even worse with your current code :

Index 0 will always contain 1 if 0 was provided (0 otherwise)

Index 1 will always contain 2 if 1 was provided (0 otherwise)

Other indexes are never populated, and will always contain 0.

```
for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter 1 if the student is present and 0 if the student is not.");
        final Scanner attendance = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inp = attendance.nextInt();
        //int y = inp;
        switch (inp)
        {
        case 1:
            number[i] = 1;
            break;
        case 0:
            number[i] = 2;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 0.");
            i--; 
        }


    }
```